# How to programmatically generate vector of Unicode characters

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to make a long list of unicode characters
"\u1", "\u2", "\u3", ... "\u10000"

I tried

```
paste0("\u",1:10000)
```

However the backslash is treated as an escape character and I get an error.

How can I insert the backslash into my character strings without it being treated as an escape character?

(I realise this question has been tackled before,
[Escaping a backslash with a backslash in R produces 2 backslashes in a string, not 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284507/escaping-a-backslash-with-a-backslash-in-r-produces-2-backslashes-in-a-string-n)
but the solution of using `cat("\\")` does not work for my situation)

Comment: `paste0("\\u",1:10000)` is giving me list like `\u1,\u2....` is this what you want ?

Comment: Escaping a backslash gives a double backslash.
So ```paste0("\\u",1:10000)``` gives me ```"\\u1", "\\u2", "\\u3", ... "\\u10000"```, which does not evaluate as unicode characters as I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite an interesting question. Note that simply `paste`ing `\\u` won't work by itself, because that will get you the two characters "\" and "u". Adding a number to the end won't magically change it into a Unicode character.

I think the most straightforward way is to build an expression as a string, and then `eval` it:

```r
nums <- 1:10
x <- paste0("\\u", nums)
x <- paste0('"', x, '"', collapse=",")
eval(parse(text=paste("c(", x, ")")))
```

Comment: `cat(paste0('\\u', 1:1000))` doesn't give you desired output ?

Comment: `cat` _displays_ a string without escaped characters. It doesn't convert the 3 characters "\", "u" and "1" into the Unicode character `\u1`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `cat()` after the `paste0()` funciton. This should give you the answer:

```
cat(paste0('\\u', 1:1000))
```